# Converting bzr's triple revision numbers

Tags: bazaar

`bzr annotate` gives revision numbers of the form `a.b.c` where `a` is the revision that was branched off; for our workflow it's more interesting to know in which revision this changed was merged back into the current repo. Can I get bzr to tell me this info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use revision prefix `mainline:`, see `bzr help revisionspec` for details.

For example,

```
bzr revno -r 1.2.3
```

prints 1.2.3, but

```
bzr revno -r mainline:1.2.3
```

prints revision number for revision that merged 1.2.3.